# nuxt build disregards .nuxtignore

Tags: nuxt.js

I have a `.nuxtignore` file at the root of my Nuxt.js project, with the following content

```
# ignore test files
*.spec.ts
```

However, when I run `nuxt build`, it still goes through all the files ending with `.spec.ts`. Those files are in subfolders within the `components` folder.

I noticed that because these files triggers some errors during the build. These errors are not related and the question is not about those, however they should not appear because the files in which they are triggered should be ignored during the build.

I'm running Nuxt.js 2.6.3, with TypeScript 3.4.5.

I've also tried to use the ignore property in `nuxt.config.ts`, as well as changing the pattern format from `*.spec.ts` to `**/*.spec.ts`. It didn't work any better.

When running `nuxt build`, I expect the files matching what is in `.nuxtignore` to be completely ignored, as if they were not existing.

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: @SimonPuente It's been a while I haven't had this issue. I guess it's gone with the more recent versions of Nuxt.js. Although, it might just be that those `.spec.ts` file simply don't trigger errors any more.

Comment: @DavidS. Do you mind to share the Nuxt version which you're using without this issue? With `2.16.3`, I'm still able to access static/images/ files that I've listed in `.nuxtignore`. In my case, I don't have custom `srcDir`, and I don't use wildcard.

Comment: I just notice this line from docs: `You can use a .nuxtignore file to let Nuxt ignore layout, page, store and middleware files in your project’s root directory (rootDir) during the build phase.`. Since `static` dir is not one of those 4 directories, I wonder if that's the culprit. However, `components` dir is neither one of them and it works for you, that's getting tricky...